# How to use i18next in react native navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

is there any way to use `useTranslation` or `withTranslation` of `i18next-react` inside react native navigator?

right now using this code, I need to restart the app each time language changes

how can I update the title dynamically as soon as language change happens in i18next (like it happens with the `useTranslation` hook)?

```js
      [ScreenNames.PartnerTab]: {
        screen: PartnersNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
          title: i18next.t('tabs:partners'),
          gesturesEnabled: false,
          tabBarIcon: createTabBarIcon(TabIcon.Partners),
          tabBarOnPress: onTabPress,
        },
      },
```

I'm changing the language like this

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
// other code
i18n.changeLanguage(languageCode);
```

Comment: Do you want your whole app to be refreshed when the language change happens?

Comment: No, that way i would have used `react-native-restart`